# place matrix and tikz side-by-side

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, tikz-styles, arrays

I'm trying to place a matrix beside a tikz picture and I put isomorphism between them but it doesn't work. Can anyone advise me?

This is my attempt:

```
 \documentclass[10pt]{article}
 \usepackage{geometry}% <-- added, 
 \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
  \usepackage{mathrsfs,array}
  \begin{document}
  \definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}

  \tikzset{graph-1/.style = {
  line cap = round,
   line join = round,
     > = triangle 45,
     x=0.7cm, y=0.7cm,
      every node/.append style = {inner ysep=2mm}
                        }
    }% end of tikzset

  \begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  $\displaystyle
  \alpha=
   \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
 \cong
 \begin{tikzpicture}[graph-1] 
 \draw (0, 1.5) -- + (2,0);
  \draw (0,-1.5) -- + (2,0);
   %%%
 \foreach \x in {0, 1}
  \draw  (\x,1.5) -- (\x+1,-1.5);

   \foreach \x/\label in {0/\scriptstyle1, 1/\scriptstyle2, 2/\scriptstyle3}
    \draw[fill=uuuuuu]  (\x,1.5) circle (1.3pt) node[above] {$\label$};
     %
        \foreach \x/\label in {0/\scriptstyle1, 1/\scriptstyle2,   2/\scriptstyle3}
    \draw[fill=uuuuuu]  (\x,-1.5) circle (1.3pt) node[below] {$\label$};
      \end{tikzpicture}
     $
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{ex}
   \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After loading the `amsmath` package and some minor adjustments it works, I think.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}%<-- added, 
 \usepackage{geometry}% 
 \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
  \usepackage{mathrsfs,array}
  \begin{document}
  \definecolor{uuuuuu}{rgb}{0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666,0.26666666666666666}

  \tikzset{graph-1/.style = {
  line cap = round,
   line join = round,
     > = triangle 45,
     x=0.7cm, y=0.7cm,
      every node/.append style = {inner ysep=2mm}
                        }
    }% end of tikzset

  \begin{figure}[h]
\[  \alpha=
   \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
 \cong
 \begin{tikzpicture}[graph-1,baseline={(fakebase.base)}] 
 \node[draw=none] (fakebase){\strut};
 \draw (0, 1.5) -- + (2,0);
  \draw (0,-1.5) -- + (2,0);
   %%%
 \foreach \x in {0, 1}
  \draw  (\x,1.5) -- (\x+1,-1.5);

   \foreach \x/\label in {0/\scriptstyle1, 1/\scriptstyle2, 2/\scriptstyle3}
    \draw[fill=uuuuuu]  (\x,1.5) circle (1.3pt) node[above] {$\label$};
     %
        \foreach \x/\label in {0/\scriptstyle1, 1/\scriptstyle2,   2/\scriptstyle3}
    \draw[fill=uuuuuu]  (\x,-1.5) circle (1.3pt) node[below] {$\label$};
      \end{tikzpicture}
\]
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{ex}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]